# How to call JSP from Servlet wihout affecting the output?

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I'm not an expert in Server-side programming nor Java-EE, and I've been looking how to achieve a pretty simple task. I'm not even sure how to express this, which made difficult to google it or to search in the API.

I have one Servlet, This Servlet is calling two different JSP pages. One of them is going to be the actual output, with html code. AFAIU this can be done by this sentence `request.getRequestDispatcher("my_jsp_page.jsp").forward(request, response);`

But the second JSP I want to call shouldn't be a part of the response/output. It's just a generated vCard (text file). So I think I can't use the previous sentence nor the `include` method, cause the `include` would affect the output, am I right?

Any tip or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Regards.

PD: Probably I didn't express myself correctly. The output of the jsp-html file is displayed on the browser, it's to say, it's the actual response. The output of the jsp-vcard file is a text downloable file, that's why I think it shouldn't be included in the output.

Comment: and how is the vCard txt file involved in all this?

Comment: Basically, @Bozho, request contains a parameter with a user ID, with this user ID I fetch the data of this user. With this data I generate the output (html file) and a downloable vcard text file. Isn't it the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems, the text file has to be generated and stored on the server, and be served in a subsequent request.

Store the file with a normal `FileOutputStream`, preferably in a location outside the webapp.

Comment: Yes, so my question is how to call a JSP to write that output on the server.

Comment: so... would you recommend to forget about JSP? I was just curious about the easiest way to do it, but yes, if it's such a pain I will just do it the classic way.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the included jsp file dont write anything to the **response**, you can include it. It will be executed(in your example generate a text file) but will not affect your final output.

Comment: Yes, the thing is to set that response as a text file on the server, but this is a hint... I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

You can read text file and set it in response. and set

```
Content-type: text/plain
```